# Why does the page number slightly move its position when a long listing code that need two pages is added?

Tags: header-footer, listings, page-numbering

I noticed that whenever I add a source code to my latex file, the numbers of the page where the code is added look displaced. I do not know if there is a reason in the listing configuration that causes this, but here is the configuration that I have written:

```
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\lstdefinestyle{customc}{
    breaklines=true,
    language=C,
    showstringspaces=false,
    keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{blue},
    commentstyle={\color{green!40!black}},
    identifierstyle=\color{black},
}
```

By using the listing command (begin{lstlisting} I write codes on my files based on this code style.
I uploaded a picture of the page number:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5aeh.png
Is there any other command or a line that I can force the page number to stay under the line?

Thanks a lot in advance for any help

```
%==========Grundeinstellungen
\documentclass[ngerman,12pt,a4paper,oneside,listof=totoc,plainfootsepline]{scrbook}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily} 
\addtokomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=-.5\baselineskip,afterskip=.25\baselineskip]{subsubsection}

\include{Kapitel/Voreinstellungen}

%===========================================================================================
%===========================================================================================
%===========================================================================================
%==========Dokument
\begin{document}
\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill\textbf{Seite}\par}
\renewcommand\contentsname{Inhaltsverzeichnis}

\tableofcontents
%\pagestyle{plain}

\listoffigures
\listoftables
\vspace{1cm}
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
%\listofformels
\vspace{1cm}
...
\endgroup
\newpage
    
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
....
\newpage    
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{12}
%\interlinepenalty 10000    
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\input{Kapitel/Hauptkapitel/Anhang}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have no idea. Please provide an MWE (from `\documentclass... ` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows your problem. It may be related to the class you use, how you set the page numbers, the packages you use, the .... We are not inclined to waste time trying to guess what you might or might not have done. --- GOM

Comment: most likely you have a twoside documentclass that has different layout for odd and even pages (unrelated to listings) but you have show no example that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I actually have only oneside documentclass. I just edited the question and added the main tex file

Comment: we can not run the example to see the issue so it does not help anyone help you. your example has nothing related to listings and an input file that is not supplied.

Comment: probably unrelated but `\include{Kapitel/Voreinstellungen}` should be `\input` never use `\include` in the preamble.